# Nginx 404 some of the images

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

**Alright, so the images in the folder some of then had a .PNG instead of .png and the file was not seen by nginx, herpy derpy derp derp**

So I'm hosting my website on nginx, I've put my images in a folder and stored it in www. Below you can see my default file code

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

server_name xxx.xx.xxx.xxx; # Replace with your domain

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 10G;

location ~* \.png {
    root html;
    index index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}

location /Images{
    root html;
}

location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
} 
}
```

And it will only render 2 images and not render rest of them for some reason, any input or help appreciated!

Comment: What is the full path to an image and what is the URI?

Comment: Full path is: /usr/share/nginx/html/Images/image1.png

Comment: Its weird because it gets the 2 first images for the website and not rest of them

Comment: So `/Image/image1.png` gives 404, are the working images in the same directory with the same extension?

Comment: Alright omg, I just relised that all the images except the ones that are working are .PNG instead of .png. I hate coding sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the nginx would read all of the .PNG files but all of my images are in .png format and so changing that solved the issue.